# DKPro Core Groovy, NP recognition not working

Tags: groovy, nlp, dkpro-core

I am verry new to groovy and i am trying to use DKPro Core for some nlp stuff. At this point i am trying to recognise name phrases within a piece of text. I can recognise tokens sentences and named entities correctly but for some reason the same doesnt work for the NP class. My code is shown below, please point out the mistake.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core', version='1.5.0',
      module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp-gpl')
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core',
    module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.text-asl',
    version='1.5.0')
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core',
    module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl',
    version='1.5.0')
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core',
    module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.text-asl',
    version='1.5.0')
@Grab(group='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core',
    module='de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp-gpl',
    version='1.5.0')

import org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException;
import org.apache.uima.fit.component.JCasConsumer_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.fit.util.JCasUtil;
import org.apache.uima.jcas.JCas;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.ner.type.NamedEntity;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Sentence;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.constituent.NP;    
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.*;

import static org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.factory.JCasFactory.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.factory.AnalysisEngineFactory.*;
import static org.apache.uima.fit.util.JCasUtil.*;

import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.*;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.ner.type.*;


def doc = createJCas();
doc.documentText = """It is unfortunate that many Nigerians, especially the younger ones, 
express surprise at the mention of elephants and lions being found within the borders of the country. 
Admittedly, the number of these animals has diminished greatly over the years due to the activities of poachers thus pushing 
some of these animals to the verge of extinction. For example, it was discovered last year 
that there are not more than 34 lions in the wild. However there should be cause for 
optimism as a rundown of just a few animals across these parks show. The Yankari 
Game Reserve in Bauchi is Nigeria's most famous and arguably the best park for observing 
wildlife. Buffaloes, waterbucks, bushbucks, hyenas, leopards, baboons, elephants and lions 
are some of the animals that can be found here. 
"The animals are best seen during the dry season, 
especially from January to April," a 
tour guide told this reporter during a safari at Yankari. """
doc.documentLanguage = "en";

runPipeline(doc,
  createEngineDescription(StanfordSegmenter),
  createEngineDescription(StanfordPosTagger),
  createEngineDescription(StanfordNamedEntityRecognizer));

// for (Token token : select(doc, Token)) {  
    // println token.coveredText + "\n\n\n"
    // }
// for (Sentence sentence : select(doc, Sentence)) {  
    // println sentence.coveredText + "\n\n\n"
    // }
for (Sentence sentence : JCasUtil.select(doc, Sentence.class)) {
println sentence.getCoveredText()+"\n\n"
for (NP nounphrase : JCasUtil.selectCovered(doc, NP.class, sentence)) { 
    println "||" + nounphrase.getCoveredText() + "||\n\n"
    }
}   
// for (Token token : select(doc, Token)) { 
    // def entity=selectCovering(NamedEntity,token).value
    // if(entity.toString().length()>2)
    // println token.coveredText +"\n\n" + entity.toString() + "\n\n\n"
    // }
```

On my output the sentences are regognised correctly, but there is nothing printed for Named Phrases.

Comment: The code provided is not working. Missing some property file.

Comment: `No file found at [classpath:/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/stanfordnlp/lib/tagger-en-wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.properties]`

Comment: @Opal the code runs for me, i probably screwed up the grabs, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

NP is part of the constituency structure. Your script does not include a constituency parser. After adding a parser to your pipeline, e.g. the Stanford parser, you can also access NPs:

```
runPipeline(doc,
  createEngineDescription(StanfordSegmenter),
  createEngineDescription(StanfordPosTagger),
  createEngineDescription(StanfordParser),
  createEngineDescription(StanfordNamedEntityRecognizer));
```

*Disclosure: I am a developer on the DKPro Core project.*